# Movie search layout tweaks with cookie persistence

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works as intended, but was wondering if there is a more efficient way of coding this.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/search/') >= 0) {
    switch ($.cookie("Layout")) {
        case "Poster":
            $("link:first").attr("href", "../css/list.css");
            break;
        case "Description":
            $("link:first").attr("href", "../css/desc.css");
    }
    $(function () {
        $(".Poster").click(function () {
            $("link:first").attr("href", "../css/list.css");
            $.cookie("Movie_Layout", "Poster", {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/media/search',
                secure: true
            });
            $('.content-genre, .searchresults').hide().delay(75).fadeIn(275);
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
        $(".Description").click(function () {
            $("link:first").attr("href", "../css/desc.css");
            $.cookie("Movie_Layout", "Description", {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/media/search',
                secure: true
            });
            $('.content-genre, .searchresults').hide().delay(75).fadeIn(275);
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
    });
} else {
    switch ($.cookie("Layout")) {
        case "Poster":
            $("link:first").attr("href", "css/list.css");
            break;
        case "Description":
            $("link:first").attr("href", "css/desc.css");
    }
    $(function () {
        $(".Poster").click(function () {
            $("link:first").attr("href", "css/list.css");
            $.cookie("Movie_Layout", "Poster", {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/media',
                secure: true
            });
            $('.content-genre, .searchresults').hide().delay(75).fadeIn(275);
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
        $(".Description").click(function () {
            $("link:first").attr("href", "css/desc.css");
            $.cookie("Movie_Layout", "Description", {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/media',
                secure: true
            });
            $('.content-genre, .searchresults').hide().delay(75).fadeIn(275);
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: well i guess both, but i wouldn't want to compromise execution time so that it looks nicer.

Comment: Ack, sorry, I deleted my comment thinking you weren't allowed to comment with only 1 rep. I asked if by "efficient" you meant code complexity or execution time.

Comment: Just to verify, you are reading 2 cookies right? "Layout" and "Movie_Layout"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a bit simpler (*in terms of code repeating*)

```
var Layout = {
    'Poster': {
        href: 'css/list.css'
    },
        'Description': {
        href: 'css/desc.css'
    }
};

function setLink(file, pathFix) {
    $('link:first').attr('href', pathFix + file);
}

$(function () {
    var currentPathFix = '',
        initialLayout = $.cookie("Layout");
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('/search/') >= 0) {
        currentPathFix = '../';
    }
    setLink(Layout( initialLayout ), currentPathFix );
    $.each(Layout, function (key, item) {
        $('.' + key).click(function () {
            setLink(item.href, currentPathFix);
            $.cookie("Movie_Layout", key, {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/media/search',
                secure: true
            });
            $('.content-genre, .searchresults').hide().delay(75).fadeIn(275);
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your code, it's some cookie-based layout selector which runs during the loading of the page. I might be wrong, but the following code runs on that assumption, since you are placing `document.ready` handlers in the code.

General tips:

- In JS, the double quote (`"`) and single quote (`'`) mean the same, but I recommend using the single quote since its cleaner.

As for code related notes, it's in the comments:

```
//Code that accesses the DOM is safer inside the `documentReady` handler
$(function () {

    //The first major redundancy is the entire code based on the presence
    //of the `/search/` keyword, we factor that out into a variable
    var search = location.href.indexOf('/search/') >= 0;

    //The first difference between the search and non-search blocks is the
    //existence of the leading `../`. The `../` exists only when search exists
    var prefix = search ? '../' : '';

    //I found out that whatever code that refers to Poster and Description
    //have the same stylesheet names. We put them into this object for further
    //convenience
    var css = {
        'Poster': 'list.css',
        'Description': 'desc.css'
    };

    //The next difference is the existence of `/search in the cookie path.
    //We also factor out the cookie config into a single varuable up here
    //so we can easily change values rather than change them down there.
    var cookieConfig = {
        expires: 365,
        secure: true,
        path : '/media' + (search ? '/search' : '')
    };

    //Common practice for jQuery users is to cache static elements, especially
    //when they are used in handlers. This avoids your code from having jQuery
    //find them every time. This practice is only true for static elements.
    //This is not applicable some cases, like for example, you want to check 
    //their existence on the DOM on button click.
    var firstLink = $('link:first');
    var content_search = $('.content-genre, .searchresults');

    //With everything factored out of the operations, what is left is the
    //common parts of the separate blocks of code, which we merge into one
    function handle(what) {
        //here, we use `what` which indicates if we are referring to Poster
        //or description. We use it as the key to determine which stylesheet
        //to use, and the value of the cookie to store.
        firstLink.attr('href', prefix + 'css/' + css[what]);
        $.cookie('Movie_Layout', what, cookieConfig);
        content_search.hide().delay(75).fadeIn(275);
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    //So here we apply our css on load. You can see how the separation of
    //the parts fit.
    firstLink.attr('href', prefix + 'css/' + css[$.cookie('Layout')]);

    //We add our handlers for each element that requires a handler. If `.Poster`
    //and `.Description` refer to multiple elements, we can do delegation, where
    //a single handler is attached to the parent, instead of to each target
    $('#postersNearestParent').on('click', '.Poster', function () {
        //In here we call handle, where we indicate which to operate
        handle.call(this, 'Poster');
    });

    $('#descriptionsNearestParent').on('click', '.Description', function () {
        handle.call(this, 'Description');
    });

});
```

Here's how short the code is without the comments. Still understandable, no?:

```
$(function () {
  var search = location.href.indexOf('/search/') >= 0;
  var prefix = search ? '../' : '';
  var css = {
    'Poster': 'list.css',
    'Description': 'desc.css'
  };
  var cookieConfig = {
    expires: 365,
    secure: true,
    path: '/media' + (search ? '/search' : '')
  };
  var firstLink = $('link:first');
  var content_search = $('.content-genre, .searchresults');

  function handle(what) {
    firstLink.attr('href', prefix + 'css/' + css[what]);
    $.cookie('Movie_Layout', what, cookieConfig);
    content_search.hide().delay(75).fadeIn(275);
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  firstLink.attr('href', prefix + 'css/' + css[$.cookie('Layout')]);

  $('#postersNearestParent').on('click', '.Poster', function () {
    handle.call(this, 'Poster');
  });

  $('#descriptionsNearestParent').on('click', '.Description', function () {
    handle.call(this, 'Description');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank-you for such a detailed description of your code! I've tried implementing your code into my page, and while it correctly defines the css for the page, when I click either the .Poster, or .Description buttons, it will not change the stylesheet.

Comment: Also, .Poster, and .Description are a single element on the page.

Comment: @Jrags87 My sample code uses delegation approach. you can change back to the non-delegated approach by changing the selectors `$('#postersNearestParent').on('click', '.Poster', function () {...` to `$('.Poster').on('click', function () {...`. Same goes for `.Description`. It also uses the [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, which only existed on jQuery 1.7